# Exporting excel to csv when field on multiple rows

Tags: excel, export-to-csv

I have been given an excel spreadsheet to convert to csv. The problem is that one of the fields is a description field in which in sentence in the description is on a separate row. So for example the first product is on row 1. The first line of the description is on row 1, the second line of the desription is on row 2, with all the other columns in that row empty. Most products have about 6 rows of description. The next product then starts on, say row 7.

I have tried exporting the data but naturally excel creates one line in a csv file per excel line so most of the rows are empty rows with just one sentence of description (e.g. , , , "sentence 2", , )

Please can you advise if there is a way to handle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to get all of the description lines into a single cell in the same row as the rest of the fields, and then get rid of the mostly-blank rows that just have the extended descriptions.

Lets assume your spreadsheet has product information in columns A and B, and the description fields in column C, like this:

[image]

In D1, enter the formula

```
=C1
```

In D2, enter the formula

```
=IF(A2<>"",C2,D1&"/"&C2)
```

Fill this down the rest of column D, producing this:

[image]

For each item, column D now contains the full description on the last row for that item.  Now we're going to get that value back up into the row with the rest of the data fields for the item.  In E1, enter the formula

```
=IF(A1<>"",OFFSET(D1,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(A2:A20)<>0,0)-1,0),"")
```

Hit Control-Enter to enter it as an array formula, and then fill down the rest of column E, producing this:

[image]

You need to enter one extra value after the last row (the "End" in the image above) to make this work.  Now you have the full description for each item in column E.  Copy column E, paste values, sort by column E to group together all the blank rows, and get rid of all the rows that don't have values in column E.  You can get rid of columns C and D at this point if you want to, which leaves you with this, which you can now export to CSV:

[image]

There's a small spreadsheet that illustrates this at http://www.filedropper.com/multiline

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to export one line per product with whole description in one place. Let's say you have a product name in column A and product descriptions in column B. You can put all descriptions in one cell with this formula (this formula assumes that you start it with cell C1):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2);B1&C2;B1)
```

Drag this formula till the last row, copy-paste as values (copy column C and paste it as values) and then delete "empty" (by column A) rows. Here you have one row per product with description in one place.